# vim regex for 'word1 NOT FOLLOWED BY word2 or word3'

Tags: regex, vim

Vim regex for volvo not followed by merc is:

```
volvo\(merc\)\@!
```

But I could not figure out regex for volvo not followed by merc and not followed by bmw. 
This does not seem to work:

```
volvo\(merc|bmw\)\@!
```

(volvomerc should not match, volvobmw should not match, volvoford should match)

Comment: Have a look at eg. inside brackets above

Comment: You need to escape the pipe: `\|`.

Comment: Oh shoot, it was pretty simple, @romaini if you write your comment as an answer, I'll accerpt!

Comment: You do not need to escape using Magic mode. Like this `\v`volvo(merc|bmw)@!

Answer (score 0):

To highligh every lines which contains volvo but not merc nor bmw, you just need the following regex:

`/^.*volvo\(.*merc\|.*bmw\)\@!.*$`

So `.*` is nedded to match every spaces or word in between.